# How to restrict user from going to Next Page if all the fields are not populated in Eclipse SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface, swt

I have a requirement like this:-

The user **shouldn't be allowed to traverse to the Next Page** in case he has not entered all the required parameters in the First Page itself. Also, in case he has entered something erroneous he should be displayed the warning and restricted from going to the Next Page. This needs to be implemented using **Eclipse Plugin Developement using JFace/SWT.**

Answer (score 0):

Check your GUIItem.value() for empty on the Next Page button action or deactivate the button until the required fields have data.

Comment: There is a method named canFlipToNextPage() which is of Boolean and used for enabling and disabling of Next Page Button. However, this method is called while creating controls and not as an Event Listener. I hope you understand the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

use WizardPage.setPageComplete(boolean complete) method (easy way), or use JFace databinding. Even better if you wire databinding with org.eclipse.jface.databinding.wizard.WizardPageSupport.

Answer (score 0):

Override the ispagecomplete method to return true only when all the values in your wizardpage are complete. When the user edits any value ensure that you have listener on these fields that call getContainer().updatebuttons() This should work for your requirement.